# R - Intervals of date & Number of rows by date

Tags: r

I have a question about a faster way to compute something about date intervals

My input:

- A data frame : one row by couple (people, period). On each row, I have the ID of a person, a date of start and a date of end.
- A period of time : All the dates day by day during two years

What i try to do is to calculate the number of people I have date by date.
I have a code which is working, but not enough efficient with a large dataset (~ from 100 k to 1 M rows).

The current problem is since I have two years of date, my code does 730 times (365x2) the following steps :

- Filter the dataset with the specific date included between the start date and the end date
- Calculate the number of unique id in the filtered dataset
  And these operations are very long or impossible with a large dataset

I am wondering if it exists a better and faster way to do these operations, like with aggregation or with another technique.

An example with a short input and output :

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# Vector of date
vector_day <- seq(ymd('2017-01-01'), ymd('2018-12-30'), by= "days")

# Input Data
df <- data.frame(
      id_people = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
      StartDate = c(as.Date("2018-11-01"), as.Date("2018-11-03"),as.Date("2018-12-01"),as.Date("2018-11-15") ,as.Date("2018-11-15")),
      EndDate = c(as.Date("2018-11-10"), as.Date("2018-12-04"),as.Date("2018-12-10"),as.Date("2018-11-17"), as.Date("2018-11-23")), 
      Gender = c("F", "F", "M", "F", "F"))


# Function to compute the number of people given a spécific date
compute_nb_f_by_day <- function(date) {

  cond1 <- df_f$StartDate <= date
  cond2 <- df_f$EndDate > date
  cond <- cond1 & cond2

  res <- length(unique(df_f[cond,]$id_people))
  return(res)

}

# An example of how the function works for on date
compute_nb_f_by_day(as.Date("2018-12-01"))

# Computation for all the dates
nb_f_by_day <- cbind(
               data.frame(vector_day),
               data.frame(nb_f_by_day <- sapply(vector_day, compute_nb_f_by_day)))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution benchmarked significantly faster than your code in the given example (your code: 0.132s; this code: 0.032s in my system). Give it a try to see if it'll significantly improve for the large dataset!

```
#-- Create the 'Interval'
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(DateInterval = StartDate %--% EndDate)

#-- Create a result df instead of using cbind (more efficient)
result_df <- data.frame(Day = vector_day, Nb = NA)

#-- Get intervals that contain the days in vector_day
result_df$Nb <- sapply(vector_day, function(day) {sum(day %within% df2$DateInterval)})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have not measured precisely the gain of speed, but it is significantly faster with m'y large datasets.